# Showing full variable name

Tags: stata

When a variable name in Stata is very long, this is shortened using `~`.

For example:

[image]

Is there a way to *force* the data editor to display the entire name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by formatting it accordingly:

```
clear
set obs 1

generate this_is_a_long_variable_name = 0
format %35.0g this_is_a_long_variable_name

browse
```

Type `help format` from Stata's command prompt for details.

Comment: The properties window will show the selected variable's details and it can be adjusted to be as wide as necessary. Also the variables window can be adjusted to be as wide as necessary so the entire name can be seen and then used to navigate to the column in the grid.

Comment: Yes i am aware. But this is not what you asked. You specifically asked for the headings in the data editor as your attached picture clearly demonstrates.

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Comment: This is not the correct answer. If you run a command like `mdesc`, the variable name is still being shortened